# ffmpeg audio cut off when merging background music with video

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to run the my ffmpeg command to merge an audio file with a video that has sound. The command I am using lowers down the volume on the audio file, since it is music and the video has audio.

Im having a problem with the audio file being cut off when the video's sound ends, instead of continuing until the video finishes.

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg \
-i thepath/input.mp4 \
-i musicpath/music.mp3 \
-filter_complex \
"[1:a]volume=-21dB,apad[A]; \
[0:a][A]amerge[out]" \
-c:v libx264 -c:a aac -map 0:v -map "[out]" \
-preset ultrafast -threads 0 -profile:v baseline \
-ac 2 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 30 -y thepath/output.mp4 2>&1
```

Im confused as to why it doesnt work as intended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`amerge` terminates with the shortest input stream, which here is the video's audio, and which doesn't span upto the video stream's end.

Add `apad` to the video's audio as well and add `-shortest` as an output option.

Full command would be

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg \
-i thepath/input.mp4 \
-i musicpath/music.mp3 \
-filter_complex \
"[0:a]apad[main]; \
 [1:a]volume=-21dB,apad[A]; \
[main][A]amerge[out]" \
-c:v libx264 -c:a aac -map 0:v -map "[out]" \
-preset ultrafast -threads 0 -profile:v baseline \
-ac 2 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 30 -shortest -y thepath/output.mp4 2>&1
```

Comment: how do i add the apad to the videos audio?

Comment: Example added..